# Can cleveref be made to use the Oxford comma for multiple citations?

Tags: punctuation, cleveref

Simple question: Is there a simple way to get `cleveref` to use the Oxford comma?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:roses}
  Roses are red.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:violets}
  Violets are blue.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
  42.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} \label{thm:orchids}
  Orchids are orchid.
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
  There exist flowers in at least three different colors.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Immediate from \cref{thm:roses,thm:violets,thm:orchids}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Should say “propositions 1, 2, and 4.”

Comment: Just wanted to make a note that the Oxford Comma is more generally known as a [Serial Comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). Mostly noted for search engine indexing.

Comment: Well, it looks like Google knows they're synonyms, but thanks :-)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you define this new command

```
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}
```

you will get Oxford comma everywhere you use multiple references like those.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:roses}
  Roses are red.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:violets}
  Violets are blue.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
  42.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} \label{thm:orchids}
  Orchids are orchid.
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
  There exist flowers in at least three different colors.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Immediate from \cref{thm:roses,thm:violets,thm:orchids}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### ADDENDUM

If you were wondering why you have to use `\newcommand` instead of `renewcommand`, this is why.

`cleveref` defines, at the beginning of the document, a lot of commands depending on the language. If you don't specify any language, `english` is loaded. This is the relevant part of `cleveref.sty`:

```
\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    ....
    \def\creflastconjunction@preamble{ and\nobreakspace}%
    ....
```

Also, you can find the following lines

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  ....
  \@ifundefined{creflastconjunction}{%
    \let\creflastconjunction\creflastconjunction@preamble%
  }{%
  ....
  }%
```

which, at the beginning of the document, assign to `\creflastconjunction` the meaning of `\creflastconjunction@preamble` when it has not been defined yet.

In other words, `\creflastconjunction` gets defined **only** after `\begin{document}`.
In fact, if you try to put the line

```
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}
```

inside the document, you will get an error. In this case, you would have written

```
\renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}
```

Comment: Does `\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}` work the same? In other words, can you replace the `\nobreakspace` with a `~`?

Comment: @MSC No problems with your substitution.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict this change of last conjunction just to English language (and do something else when \cref is issued in the context where the language is, say, German)?

Comment: As I wondered about this: with just two references (`\cref{thm:roses,thm:violets}`) this correctly expands to `propositions 1 and 2`, without the extra comma.

Answer (score 11):

Simple answer: You can use

```
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}
```

From the manual:

> `\creflastconjunction` is used between the penultimate and final cross-reference in a list of more than two  [pg. 12, at least for the 2012-03-07 version of the manual I have]

---

Redoing your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage\[standard\]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and~}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:roses}
  Roses are red.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:violets}
  Violets are blue.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
  42.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} \label{thm:orchids}
  Orchids are orchid.
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
  There exist flowers in at least three different colors.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Immediate from \cref{thm:roses,thm:violets,thm:orchids}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image: The compiled example, saying "Immediate from propositions 1, 2, and 4."]

Comment: This is already in my answer...

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @LukeMaurer: You'd think so, but surprisingly not.

Comment: So cleveref is actually checking for the existence of that macro? Weird. \*shrug\*

Comment: @karlkoeller: So it is!  I guess great minds think alike; I must have started writing my answer while you were finishing writing yours.

Comment: Plus for referring the manual.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict this change of last conjunction just to English language (and do something else when \cref is issued in the context where the language is, say, German)?

Comment: @Just_A_Man That’s a good question – you should [ask it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as a full-fledged one!  I’m afraid I don’t know the answer myself, though.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `\crefmultiformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefmultiformat{proposition}{propositions~#2#1#3}%
  { and~#2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{, and~#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:roses}
  Roses are red.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}\label{thm:violets}
  Violets are blue.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}
  42.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition} \label{thm:orchids}
  Orchids are orchid.
\end{proposition}

\begin{theorem}
  There exist flowers in at least three different colors.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  Immediate from \cref{thm:roses,thm:violets,thm:orchids}.
  Immediate from \cref{thm:roses,thm:violets}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aha! It's a little piecemeal (will need to repeat for different theorem sets), but it should work. Thanks.

Comment: @LukeMaurer see karlkoeller's answer for a solution affecting all reference types.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `#2#1#3` instead of `#1#2#3`?

Comment: Is it possible to restrict this change of last conjunction just to English language (and do something else when `\cref` is issued in the context where the language is, say, German)?