# Getting Natbib to use an Oxford comma

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, punctuation

Is there a way to get Natbib to use an Oxford comma when citing multiple papers? I would like to retain the automatic formatting/sorting when using `\citet{}`. I don't want this to affect the behaviour of `\citep{}`.

[image: Oxford comma example]

I have found examples of similar behaviour using normal references:

- [Can cleveref be made to use the Oxford comma for multiple citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161338/can-cleveref-be-made-to-use-the-oxford-comma-for-multiple-citations)

but nothing for Natbib for what I want. If this involves creating a new command such as `\citetoxf{}` is no great loss, but I would be interested to see if both solutions are possible.

**MWE:**

```
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{author00,
title = {{A Title}},
publisher = {Alpha},
year = {2008},
editor = {Author, A},
address = {London}
}
@book{buthor00,
title = {{B Title}},
publisher = {Bravo},
year = {1990},
author = {Buthor, B},
address = {New York}
}
@book{cuthor00,
title = {{C Title}},
publisher = {Charlie},
year = {1960},
author = {Cuthor, C},
address = {Tokyo}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=endash,figurewithin=section,tablewithin=section]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue]{hyperref} % Colour links.
\usepackage{cleveref,lipsum}
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib} % Nice references.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\begin{document}
\noindent
No Oxford comma: \citet{author00,buthor00,cuthor00}. \\
Oxford comma: \citet{author00,buthor00}, and \citet{cuthor00}. \\
Automatic sorting: \citet{cuthor00,buthor00,author00}.
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your write-up is quite confusing, I'm afraid: It looks like the change you want to make is *not* about getting an "Oxford comma" between the penultimate and final items in the list. Instead, the change appears to be about getting the word **and** inserted after the final ("Oxford") comma in the list of citation call-outs. Note that it is not recommended to use `\citet` with multiple arguments and authoryear-style citation call-outs. Using `\citep` with multiple arguments is OK, though -- you just don't get the word "and" after the final comma...

Comment: That is close to impossible.  You would have to hook into the Natbib code to manipulate the printing of the last citation in the list.  Having once debugged a Natbib problem I can tell you that the code is horrible and absolutely unreadable.  If you want to tackle this, `\NAT@citexnum` is the macro you want to look at.

Comment: If you can, just use `biblatex` instead.  It has `natbib` emulation.

Comment: I stand by my earlier comment, which was based on a recommendation that's made in the user guide of the `natbib` package: *Don't use `\citet` to generate citation call-outs to multiple entries*  unless all entries have the same author(s).