# cleveref: How reference several items in an unnumbered theorem-like environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, enumitem, cleveref

I want the output from the command

```
\cref{prob:third-problem,prob:fourth-problem}
```

on the first line of the content of the first chapter — the one whose output (with two `??`s) is marked in the displayed page below — will become "Exercises 2.3 and 2.4" (without any quotes), just like any other command of the form `\cref{first,second}`.

(And similarly for something like `\cref{first,fourth,fifth}` with a list of more than two problem references.)

How can this be done with `cleveref`?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% theorems    
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
  numbered=no,
  spaceabove=3\topsep,
  postheadspace=0pt    
]{probs}
\declaretheorem[
  name=EXERCISES,
  style=probs,
]{problemscontent}

\newenvironment{problems}
{\problemscontent}
{\endproblemscontent}

% lists
\usepackage{enumitem}

% For exercises
\newcounter{problemnumber} % number exercises within each chapter

\newlist{problemsenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problemsenum,1]{%...
    label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
    ref={\arabic*}, % strips formatting!
    before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax},
    after=\stepcounter{problemsenumi}\setcounter{problemnumber}{\value{problemsenumi}},
    start=\value{problemnumber}
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@problemsenumi}{\maybe@thechapter{\thechapter}}
\protected\def\maybe@thechapter#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\value{chapter}%
  \else
    #1.%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newlist{problempartsenum}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[problempartsenum,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily(\alph*),
    ref={(\alph*)},%, % strips formatting!
    before=\vspace{\dimexpr+6pt-\medskipamount\relax},
}

% links
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{%
  breaklinks=true,%
  colorlinks, citecolor=red,%
}

%% Allow ref to section n, not section m.n
%% From 'third installment' of  answer by Christian Hupfer 
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608
\usepackage{xparse,xassoccnt}
\usepackage[user,hyperref]{zref}
\RegisterPostLabelHook{\zlabel}
% Replace \arabic{section} with \Roman{section} etc. as needed:
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{section}{\arabic{section}} 
\zref@addprop{main}{section}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
    \ref{#1}}{%
    \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}%
       {\zref@extract{#1}{section}}}}
 \makeatother
%% End of code from Christian Hupfer's answer

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Exercise~#1#3}
\Crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Exercise~#1#3}
\crefformat{problemscontent}{#2\textnormal{#3}}
\Crefformat{problemscontent}{#2\textnormal{#3}}

\newcommand\crefprob[2]{\cref{#1}~\ref{#2}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprob[2]{Exercises~\textup{\ref{#1}}--\textup{\ref{#2}}}
\newcommand\crefrangeprobpart[2]{\textup{\ref{#1}}--\textup{\ref{#2}}}
\newcommand\crefprobandrangeprobpart[3]{\cref{#1}~\textup{\ref{#2}}--\textup{\ref{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}\label{chap:1}
\setcounter{problemnumber}{1}

See \cref{prob:first-problem} in a different chapter. And \cref{prob:third-problem,prob:fourth-problem}.

See also \cref{prob:chap1-number2}~\ref{prob-part:one-part-b}, that is, 
\crefprob{prob:chap1-number2}{prob-part:one-part-b}.

And consider \crefrangeprob{prob:chap1-number1}{prob:chap1-number2} in this chapter.

What about parts \crefrangeprobpart{prob-part:one-part-a}{prob-part:one-part-b} 
of \cref{prob:chap1-number2} in this chapter?
That is, \crefprobandrangeprobpart{prob:chap1-number2}{prob-part:one-part-a}{prob-part:one-part-b}.

Or \crefprobandrangeprobpart{prob:first-problem}{prob-part:first-problem-part-a}{prob-part:first-problem-part-b} 
in another chapter.

\begin{problems}
\begin{problemsenum}

\item\label{prob:chap1-number1}
A question.

\item\label{prob:chap1-number2}

\begin{problempartsenum}

\item\label{prob-part:one-part-a}
Why is $a = b$?

\item\label{prob-part:one-part-b}
Why is $d = c$?

\item\label{prob-part:one-part-c}
Is $x=y$?

\end{problempartsenum}

\end{problemsenum}

\end{problems}

%%%
\chapter{Second}\label{chap:2}
\setcounter{problemnumber}{1}

Refer to \cref{prob:first-problem} in this chapter---specifically, to 
\crefprob{prob:first-problem}{prob-part:first-problem-part-b}.


And see \crefrangeprob{prob:third-problem}{prob:fifth-problem}.

\section{First section}

\begin{problems}\label{probs:seconeprobs}
\begin{problemsenum}

\item \label{prob:first-problem}
First problem.

\begin{problempartsenum}

\item\label{prob-part:first-problem-part-a}
Why is $a = b$?

\item\label{prob-part:first-problem-part-b}
Why is $d = c$?

\item\label{prob-part:first-problem-part-c}
Is $x=y$?

\end{problempartsenum}

\item 
Second problem.

\end{problemsenum}
\end{problems}

\section{Second section}

\begin{problems}\label{probs:sectwoprobs}
\begin{problemsenum}

\item \label{prob:third-problem}
First problem.

\item \label{prob:fourth-problem}
Second problem.

\begin{problempartsenum}

\item\label{prob-part-fourth-problem-part-a}
Is it?

\item\label{prob-part-fourth-problem-part-b}
Why not?

\end{problempartsenum}

\item \label{prob:fifth-problem}
Fifth problem.

\end{problemsenum}
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image: Missing cleveref plural and "and".]

*Notes:*

1. The `problems` environment has been defined in a special way so as to allow `cleveref` references to items enumerated there, without that environment itself being a numbered theorem-like environment. That and associated command and `cleveref` constructions are gleaned from various answers in other posts. Those posts include [Reference with just part of section number after decimal point](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383606/reference-with-just-part-of-section-number-after-decimal-point) and
   [How use cleveref to get theorem-like name and list item number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327606/how-use-cleveref-to-get-theorem-like-name-and-list-item-number).
2. My actual, much more complex document, does use the `memoir` document class. However, for this MWE, the `book` class likely could be used as well, possibly if additional packages were explicitly loaded.

Comment: This can be fixed by including `\crefname{problemsenumi}{Exercise}{Exercises}` in the preamble. Unfortunately, if the `\cref` argument consists of more than two items for the `problemsenumi` type, such as `\cref{prob:third-problem,,prob:chap1-number2,,prob:fourth-problem}`, then the output "Exercises 2, 2.3 and 2.4" is missing the desired Oxford comma (the comma preceding the "and".

Comment: The Oxford comma issue is addressed in a new post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502718/cleveref-how-include-oxford-comma-in-cref-argument-having-several-items.

Comment: Sorry, I should have searched first: the Oxford comma issue was solved in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161340/13492.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by including

```
\crefname{problemsenumi}{Exercise}{Exercises}
```

in the preamble.

(The missing Oxford (serial) comma that I prefer can be inserted as answered in [Can cleveref be made to use the Oxford comma for multiple citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161338/can-cleveref-be-made-to-use-the-oxford-comma-for-multiple-citations), namely, by including `\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{, and\nobreakspace}`.