# Removing Oxford Comma from `cleveref`

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

When citing multiple theorems, `cleveref` sometimes uses an Oxford Comma (also known as a Serial Comma, apparently), and sometimes doesn't. I would like for it not to.

Note that there is a very similar question on tex.SE: [Can cleveref be made to use the Oxford comma for multiple citations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161338/can-cleveref-be-made-to-use-the-oxford-comma-for-multiple-citations). I tried using `\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ and~}` (this can be un/commented from the MWE below to see its affect), but it did not work. In fact, if one has it, then one can see there is a double space in the first list.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ and~}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\label{thm1}
    Thm 1
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
\label{prop}
    Prop 1
\end{prop}

\begin{thm}
    \label{thm3}
    Thm 3
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
\label{lem}
    Lem 1
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
    \label{thm5}
    Thm 5
\end{thm}

\cref{thm1,prop,lem}

\cref{thm1,thm3,thm5}

\end{document}
```

A fix, of course, is to just write `\cref{thm1}, \cref{thm3} and \cref{thm5}`, but this is removing beneficial functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define also `\creflastgroupconjunction` as mentioned at the end of section 8.1.1 of the manual (p. 14).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}

\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ and~}
\newcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ and~}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\label{thm1}
    Thm 1
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}
\label{prop}
    Prop 1
\end{prop}

\begin{thm}
    \label{thm3}
    Thm 3
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}
\label{lem}
    Lem 1
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}
    \label{thm5}
    Thm 5
\end{thm}

\cref{thm1,prop,lem}

\cref{thm1,thm3,thm5}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had a search in the manual, but didn't spot this part. It's very strange how it defaults to having the Oxford Comma for one but not the other!